# Authenticate action unreachable OpenId ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following this example: [OpenID Authentication with ASP.NET MVC3 , DotNetOpenAuth and OpenID-Selector](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx)

I started a new MVC4 project and add the OpenId code as suggested in the article above.

A break point on the Authenticate action in AccountController is unreachable.

Clicking on Google or Yahoo takes me to this blank page: http://localhost:37638/Account/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=

Comment: I tried toggling files(JS, CSS, _layout and web.config) between the MVC3 project and my MVC4 project, still same behavior.

Comment: The same behavior is seen with a new MVC3 project. This leads me to believe that there some settings different in the sample project downloaded from the link above. Which one though?

Comment: I used WINMerge to compare my MVC3 project with the sample and can not find anything different that could be the cause of this strange behavior.

Comment: 'code' [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {'code' // Removing the Authorize attribute on the controller class makes it work. What are ramifications of removing the Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: do you have appropriate bindingRedirects in your web.config file for MVC 1-3 to redirect to MVC 4?

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Yes I do, the project is straight out of the box. Brand new project with just the files needed for OpenId added.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to removing the Authorize attribute on the controller is to add the AllowAnonymous attribute to the action, that has fixed the issue for me.